# how to add new TextRange.Run to PowerPoint textbox?

Tags: c#, vba, textbox, vsto, powerpoint

I would like to copy some text with its formatting. If whole text is formatted in one way then it is very easy to do, but I can not manage with copying text which is formatted in different ways (for example some part of text is bold some not).

There is something like Run, and I know how to read it (and how to add it using open xml, but the add-in has to work on opened presentation), but how can I add it/insert into some textbox?  I can not find any method like Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Runs.Add()  or Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Runs(1).Insert()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found how to do it:

```
for (int k = 0; k < sourceShapeProps.textFrame.TextRange.Runs.Count; k++)
   {
    var run = sourceShapeProps.textFrame.TextRange.get_Runs(k + 1, 1);
    var characters = cell.Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.get_Characters(run.Start, run.Length);
    characters.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = run.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB;
    characters.Font.Bold = run.Font.Bold;
    characters.Font.Italic = run.Font.Italic;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

How to assign value to,

```
Shape1.TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(1).Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

But the above code doesn't make the 1st block of text in run to true, no bold is applied.

Comment: Just like I posted above:      var characters = cell.Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.get_Characters(run.Start, run.Length);
    characters.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

Comment: You may also using some font that has no "bold" option.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it seems only Runs is able to be used for get and doesn't support set, which is to be done by the way you said. I just rotated runs in a foreach and used character block to update the values.